# check if 3 number are odd with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if these 3 numbers are odd:

```
if ( ($pezzi % 1) && ($base % 1) && ($altezza % 1) ) {
}
```

Why my script don't work? I do not understand why..

Comment: Try using `% 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( ($pezzi % 2 !=0) and ($base % 2 !=0) and ($altezza % 2 !=0) ) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
if((number1 % 2) != 0 AND (number2 % 2) != 0 AND (number3 % 2) != 0){
    -- do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
    if ($pezzi%2!=0 && $base%2!=0 && $altezza%2!=0) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is true. You just didn't compare it with 0:

```
if(($pezzi % 2) != 0 && ($base % 2) != 0 && ($altezza % 2) != 0){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ($pezzi & 1) && ($base & 1) && ($altezza & 1) ) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.